# Laptop sometimes loses WiFi connection when phone connects to WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, billion

#### Environment

- Laptop A (Windows Vista)
- Laptop B (Windows 7)
- Phone A (iOS)
- Phone B (Android)
- Phone C (Android)
- Wireless 802.11 g/n 2.4GHz router (Billion 7800NL)

#### Problem

When Phone C enters the house and connects to the wireless LAN, Laptop B disconnects from the wireless network; Windows shows that it isn't connected to a wireless network at all. When this happens, all of the other devices stay connected and work normally.

Once when the laptop was connected while Phone C was already in the house, the problem happened again after a while of normal use.

#### Troubleshooting

- Tried reconnecting to the network. Windows said it couldn't. Another time it did connect, but it said it had limited connectivity.
- Tried restarting the laptop. This didn't help.
- Tried restarting the router. This fixed the problem temporarily.
- Ensured that the router was acting as a DHCP server and had enough IP addresses available.
- Ensured that none of the laptops or phones were assigning themselves static IP addresses.
- Tried moving the laptop close to the router. This didn't help.
- Checked that the IPv4 addresses were unique.

Any ideas about what could be causing this? It sounds like it could be a problem with the laptop or the router.

Comment: Did you try restarting the phone?

Comment: Are Laptop B and Phone C using the "n" wifi connection by any chance? I'm guessing laptop A and Phone A are not using "n" wireless connections. Is that true?

Comment: @skub I just checked, and they're all using n.

Comment: @LM126, not that I remember. However, I actually have access to two different phones of the same model, and both of them cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was an update for the wireless card driver available through Windows Update. After installing it, the problem no longer occurred, so I suspect it was a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a they might be getting conflicting IP addresses or a bug in the routers software. You can try making sure they are getting different ip addresses or check to see if there are any updates available for your router.

Comment: I was thinking it might be an address conflict, too. I checked that today, and they seem to be using unique router-assigned IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Crazy if you temporarily Assign a static ip to your laptop does it still disconnect when phone c comes in? I'm guessing it's a bug in the driver of the wifi card or a bug in the router.